# Android - Start a service on boot not working

Tags: java, android, service, manifest

In my app, I'm trying to start a service on phone boot. But it's not responding at all.

```
public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, AppServices.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

In the manifest, I did this.

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceStarter" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Inside the service `AppServices.class`

```
onCreate {
Toast.makeText(getAppContext(),
"Phone booted", Toast.length_long).show(); //just for test
    andMyOtherCodeAsWell();
    }
```

But it's not working at all, can anyone help me with the issue?

**SOLVE** working after 15 secs of the boot even the app is not running in the background(manually cleared by user).

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

Comment: Is it showing your Toast , on boot ?

Comment: This just for test, the main task is run the service. And the toast is actually inside the service not in the receiver.

Comment: But I can see that Toast is inside the BroadcastReceiver, so it should show on device boot.

Comment: if you attempt to call startService() when your application is not in the foreground then an IllegalStateException will be thrown - Oreo behaviour changes.

Comment: You can't add `getAppContext()` or `this` inside a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @ArghadipDasCEO, then put a Toast after context.startService(); to check if the broadcast receiver is working or not

Comment: It's not working! not responding at all, I've tested from 2 days and also the app is running in the background

Comment: have you given permission in menifest ? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

Comment: @Lucifer NO....

Comment: @ArghadipDasCEO, then you need to give the persmission , also you need to check it runtime......

Comment: @Lucifer `also you need to check it runtime` - no it's not a dangerous permission, it's normal level.

Comment: `<uses-permission android.permission.also you need to check it runtime/>`? what is the permission @MarkKeen

Comment: no - you only check DANGEROUS permissions at runtime, `BOOT_COMPLETED` is normal protection level, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 3):

Check your API version. Oreo behaviour changes - If you attempt to call `startService()` when your application is not in the foreground then an IllegalStateException will be thrown.

Docs :

> Context.startForegroundService() method starts a foreground service.
>   The system allows apps to call Context.startForegroundService() even
>   while the app is in the background. However, the app must call that
>   service's startForeground() method within five seconds after the
>   service is created.

so call:

`context.startForegroundService()` in your `BroadcastReceiver` and promote your service to a foreground service within 5 seconds of it starting by showing a notification i.e.: `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)`;

Also make sure you have the correct permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` was the issue

Comment: what is your target API?

Comment: `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />`

Comment: How to start the service when the app is not in background?

Comment: ok, so if you run your app on a Oreo device (emulator/real device), it will throw an `IllegalStateException` as described above - more info - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try to put a breakpoint inside the `BroadcaseReceiver` and then send `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast via adb with the following command:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.example.package
```

(Don't forget to change `com.example.package` to your package name).

This way you can check and see if your broadcast receiver is getting called.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I can't leave a comment because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Its proper answer, why it should be a comment ?

Comment: @Lucifer doesn't provide a solution to the OP's question. Simply tells a way to debug the issue. I'm not saying it is not constructive, just that it should've been a comment.